# grab specifc value from a string

Tags: javascript, angularjs-scope

Does anyone know how could I get the image URL from a string? I may get 2 URL's or more than two delimited by a comma and some of them won't not be an image.

```
 var sample_str = "http://domain.com/test.html,http://another.domain.com/images/1234.jpg";
```

Basically what I want to do is get only the image URL and omit the rest.

```
 http://another.domain.com/images/1234.jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use split and run through the values.  Along the lines of:

```
var s = "http://domain.com/test.html,http://another.domain.com/images/1234.jpg";
var ss = s.split(",");
for (var i=0; i<ss.length; i++) {
//for (var i in ss) {
    document.write(ss[i]);
    document.write("<br/>");
}
```

Comment: Shout if you cannot work from here or need a more complete answer.

Comment: Don't use `for..in` for iterating arrays.

Comment: @Xotic750 I get the impression this will be a very small value list, so didn't think it would matter.

Comment: @Xotic750 Why we shouldn't use `for..in` for iterating over arrays?

Comment: `for..in` is for enumeration. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea Also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in `Note: for..in should not be used to iterate over an Array where index order is important.` and if you are then use at your own peril.

Comment: For the sake of semantics I have updated it, but since no actual changes are being made to the array I see no difference.  Thanks to @Xotic750 for highlighting some best practices.  Either way, hopefully it helps the question poster.

Comment: [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write) has its place occasionally as it has its own set of problems, when possible it is best to avoid it and use `document.createElement` and friends. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

Comment: Thanks so much Anthony, but how do I know which one is an image link?

Comment: thanks a lot, I will add then something like this inside the loop:      var extension = ss[i].substr((file.lastIndexOf('.') + 1));
            switch (extension) {
                case 'jpg':
                    alert('image url');
                case 'png':
                    alert('image url');
                case 'gif':
                    alert('image url');
                    break;                         // the alert ended with pdf instead of gif.
                default:
                    alert('something else');
            }

Comment: If I were to choose between using [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), [`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) or [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) then I would opt for `slice`. The ES6 [`endsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith) does not have wide enough support yet. You could also `split('.')` and `pop`.